# How split between Number pyspark or NLP

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp

I want to do a multiple split in one column of my dataframe.
Example:

```
s = "Cras mattis MP the -69661/69662;69663 /IS4567"
```

How can I obtain:

```
s = ['Cras', 'mattis', 'MP', 'the', '69661', '69662', '69663', 'IS4567' ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way using SparkSQL's builtin functions [sentences()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#sentences) and [flatten()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#flatten) [need spark 2.4.0+ for *flatten()*]:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('new_s', expr('flatten(sentences(s))')).show(truncate=False)    
#+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
#|s                                            |new_s                                               |
#+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
#|Cras mattis MP the -69661/69662;69663 /IS4567|[Cras, mattis, MP, the, 69661, 69662, 69663, IS4567]|
#+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

what [sentences()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) does from Apache Hive documentation:

> Tokenizes a string of natural language text into words and sentences, where each sentence is broken at the appropriate sentence boundary and returned as an array of words. The 'lang' and 'locale' are optional arguments. For example, sentences('Hello there! How are you?') returns ( ("Hello", "there"), ("How", "are", "you") ).

Comment: is `sentences` is not part of `pyspark.sql.function` ? Can we use it without using select ?

Comment: @PIG, you can always run SparkSQL using `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` with dataFrame API.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) functions which takes regex pattern to split data.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('ns', f.split('s', "[^a-zA-Z0-9']+")).show(10,False)
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|s                                            |ns                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|Cras mattis MP the -69661/69662;69663 /IS4567|[Cras, mattis, MP, the, 69661, 69662, 69663, IS4567]|
+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

*Note :* `"[^a-zA-Z0-9']+"` will take care of basic English characters But if you want to include special characters, you can use generic `\p{L}` instead of `a-zA-Z` Like `"[^\\p{L}0-9']+"`